# Flawed induction proof

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

I read an example inductive proof as follows:

[image]

In the [source document](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/347.summer19/induction-errors.pdf), it says this is flawed and has some subtlety that hides the flaw. I am not able to identify the same. What's hidden here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very subtle: the equality does *not* hold when $n=1$.